# Is there a better way in selecting images in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have pictures imported into my oop like this. Currently however whenever I copy or move the file it obviously stop being able to read it.

```
frmLayout.picwater.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Ceejay\Desktop\winBTECGradeAndUcasCal\winBTECGradeAndUcasCal\Pictures\water2.png")
```

Comment: Very hard to guess why you'd write code like this.  Either use Project > Properties > Resources or Application.StartupPath or OpenFileDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stream to load your image

```
Public Function LoadImageFromStream(ByVal cImage As String) As Image
    Dim image As Image = Nothing
    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(cImage, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        Dim buffer(fs.Length) As Byte
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, fs.Length - 1)
        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - 1)
            image = image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return image
End Function
```

In your code, you can call it like

```
frmLayout.picwater.Image = LoadImageFromStream("C:\Users\Ceejay\Desktop\winBTECGradeAndUcasCal\winBTECGradeAndUcasCal\Pictures\water2.png")
```

But you should really consider @Hans Passant's comment of not using a hard-coded file path